# saving xml file in Flex,Webapplication,asp.net

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex

I am creating a xml object and adding a xml element via coding in flex.  Finally, I need to save it as a xml file.  How can this be done?

```
private var newtreeItems:XML = <items>
      <page caption="Page">                                                         
           <scene caption="Scene"></scene>                                                                   
      </page>                                           
     </items>;
```

I need to save this as xml file from browser.

please send some link regarding this type of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible *only* using a SWF running in the browser. As mentioned Air (the desktop variant for the Flash platform) can do it using the [File Class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/File.html).

Using the browser plug-in you are limited to:

- upload a file to a server
- download a file from a server

Here is Adobe documentation on how to do it in Flex 3 (MXML and AS3):

- [Working with file upload and download](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_9.html)
- [Example: Uploading and downloading files](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_9.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is your app an AIR application or just a Flex web app.

From AIR you can save files to disk.
For Flex web app you need a proxy script on a server that will get the xml as parameter from your flex app.. save it on server as a file and then send back to flex the file link where you can use again flex to save it :)

Not so easy to do it...

If someone else does not have already another solution for this i will create a tutorial for you later.